# Best way to connect database in PHP with classes

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, subclass

I'm looking for the best way to connect MySQL database in PHP with PDO driver when using classes.

I don't want to make connection in every file. I did following `class.DbConnection.php`, is it useable in this case or should I do this totally different way? Is it possible to use subclasses or something?

Is this safe way to connect to database with PDO?

```
class DbConnection {

    protected $type = "mysql";
    protected $host = "127.0.0.1";
    protected $db = "databaseName";
    protected $user = "myUser";
    protected $pass = "myPass";

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db_connect();
    }


    public function db_connect() {

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($this->type . ':host=' . $this->host . '; dbname=' . $this->db, $this->user, $this->pass);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 5);
            $pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            include("dbError.php");
            die();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So here comes yet another DB wrapper. Here's why you are going wrong way: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes

Comment: _I don't want to make connection in every file_ What do you think you will be doing with this class other than instantiating it (connecting) in every file

Comment: @RiggsFolly, if I have many classes whom get data from same database... Do I have to make new connection in every class

Comment: **NO No no** Pass the connection around to each class that requires it. Preferably as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, so do I use `extends` somehow?

Comment: **No** just pass the `$conn` about as a parameter to `__construct($conn)` and save it as a class property. Otherwise you end up making User a subclass of Database. But that relationship does not actually exist